# Up down arrow in table MVC asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list with up and down button on the left. How to make the first table row with only "down" button and the last table row with "Up" button? This is my code in view.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {    
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="up">Up</a> | 
                <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
            </td>
            <td class="personName">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td class="personOrder">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Order)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" class ="personID" value=@item.ID />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: You use a item index and a condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `IEnumerable`'s `First()` and `Last()` to make it work

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{    
    <tr>
        <td>
            @if(item != Model.First())
            {
                <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
            }
            @if(item != Model.Last())
            {
                <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
            }
        </td>
        <td class="personName">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td class="personOrder">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Order)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" class ="personID" value=@item.ID />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define variable to help You get track of current index. Now it's become simple to identify current element. Can also use for loop.

```
@{int x = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @if (x != 0)
            {
                <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
            }
            @if (x != Model.Count() - 1)
            {
                <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
            }
            x++;
        </td>
        <td class="personName">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td class="personOrder">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Order)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" class="personID" value=@item.ID />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question seems more related to "how things should render", you could also use CSS `first-child`:

```css
TABLE TR:first-child a.up{display:none;}
TABLE TR:last-child a.down{display:none;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
      <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      anything
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
      <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      anything
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
      <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      anything
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```